# Is there an easy way to separate categorical vs continuous variables into two dataset in R

Tags: r, variables, model

Say I have about 500 variables available, and I'm trying to do variable selection for my model ( response is binary )

I am planning on doing some kind of corr analysis for all continuous, then do categorical after.

Since there's a lot of variables involved, I can't do it manually.

Is there a function that I can use ? or maybe a module ?

Comment: Are the categorical variables already stored as factors or characters?

Comment: you need to explain what your definition of categorical and continuous is

Answer (score 5):

I'm using `iris` data set avaialbe in `R`. Then

```
sapply(iris, is.factor)
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
       FALSE        FALSE        FALSE        FALSE         TRUE
```

will tell you weather your columns are factor or not. So using

```
iris[ ,sapply(iris, is.factor)]
```

you can pick factor columns only. And

```
iris[ ,!sapply(iris, is.factor)]
```

will give you those columns which are not factor. You can also use `is.numeric`, `is.character` and different other versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str(df)` to see which columns are factors and which are not (df is your dataframe). For example, for data iris in R:

```
str(iris)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Or, you can use `lapply(iris,class)`

```
$Sepal.Length
[1] "numeric"

$Sepal.Width
[1] "numeric"

$Petal.Length
[1] "numeric"

$Petal.Width
[1] "numeric"

$Species
[1] "factor"
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that returns logical for number of unique value less than some fraction of the total and I'm picking 5%:

```
 discreteL <- function(x) length(unique(x)) < 0.05*length(x)
```

Now `sapply` it (with negation for continuous variables) to the data.frame:

```
 > str( iris[ , !sapply(iris, discreteL)] )
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
```

You could have picked a particular number, say 15, as your criterion I suppose.

I should make clear that the statistical theory suggests this procedure to be dangerous for the purpose outlined. Just picking the variables that are most correlated with a binary response is not well-supported. There have been many studies that show better approaches to variable selection. So my answer is really only how to do the separation, but not an endorsement of the overall plan that you have vaguely described.

Comment: This might not work on something like an ID number where all categorical values are distinct

Comment: True 'nuff. I suppose one could also look at `table(diff(x))`.